# XCode's Instruments for Core Animation keeps showing null

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

[image: instruments]

I am trying to see the fps of several UITableView in my iOS application.
Though following [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice.html), the core animation template keeps showing null.  Other instruments seems working as expected.  Is there any configuration I missed?

Thanks in advance.

ps. The environment is xCode 6.2 running iPhone 6 Simulator on iOS8.2

Comment: What kind of app is it?

Comment: It's an iOS chat application.  I am trying to profile the scrolling performance of one of the UITableView in it.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm seeing this on XCode 6.3 too.

Comment: Not yet, the issue still remains.

Comment: It works ok on actual devices so I guess the instrument is not for simulator?

Comment: just got this as well after upgrading to 6.3.2, my best guess is that its just a bug.

Comment: I am using Instruments 6.4 and the Core Animation FPS only works on an actual device

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-CoreAnimation.html

> Core Animation template
>   Library pane (only appears when an iOS device is connected)

I feel like this is Apple's way of saying this instrument only works on device. I tested it myself and it has only worked on device so far for me.

If you look here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-TimeProfiler.html

the time profiler, which does work on the simulator, does not have the same line about only appearing in the library pane when an iOS device is connected. So I think it is safe to say that Core Animation (and a few others like the [Energy Usage Instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-EnergyUsage.html)) only will work with a device.